# how to concatinate two string from single column in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, lambda

I have a database called news and have a column called description, I have two take the Last two entries from table (description column) and display the result as a single string string , ie, want to append the data in the Second last column to the last data. But I am not able to append the text,and deleted the code.

controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var news = db.News.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(news);
    }
```

view

```
@model Project.Models.News

<a href="@Url.Action("NewsInnerPage", "News")">
                    <marquee>
                        <p>
                            @Html.Raw(Model.Description)                                
                        </p>
                    </marquee>
                </a>
```

sql column

[image]

I want to get the value from table last two entries as a single string . can anyone please help me to write the code . how can i append string ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var news = db.News.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).Take(2).ToList();
var concatenatedNews = new News {
     Description = news[0].Description + news[1].Description
};
```

or you could do it all in one line

```
var news = new News { Description = string.Join("", news.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).Take(2).Select(u => u.Description)) };
```

Comment: cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IQueryable<news>'

Comment: like i said, i forgot to apply ToList, check the query again var news = db.News.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).Take(2).ToList();

Comment: but it is showing as two line, I just want to display as a single line instead of two means appending one to another

Comment: i suspect that you have a line break somewhere in the strings, could you paste the strings that you want concatenated?

Comment: no, have not given the line break , but now also it showing the same mistake as two lines

Comment: not sure what you mean by the same mistake as two lines? is the result correct but it gets shown on 2 lines? anyway, i just notice that you have html as a string so you have 2 tags in a string so it will render them on different line, you need some javascript to get the desired effect, or some string processing to get the text from you tags and concatenate those